# Video Broadcasting

Tags: flash, video, webcam, broadcast

For fun I'd like to recreate http://chatroulette.com/.  Basically i need to be able to stream webcam video from one computer to another using flash.

I'm new to flash.  Are there libraries out there for this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried http://ustream.tv ?  or were you looking for more of a private intranet solution?  chatroulette.com was down at time of this answer..

Comment: Yeah, I have.  The ustream.tv and justin.tv api's both seem to require you to be logged in, which would defeat the purpose of anonymous video chat.

Looking for something a little lower level than those apis.  

thanks for the suggestion.